# MySQL combining 3 tables with 2 from same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

So, am bad at words, i will describe it as in pictures.

This is **MATSH** table in my database. My goal, is to replace Mang_id, Voistkond_1_id and Voistkond_2_id with names from other tables.

MATSH.Mang_id = MANG.Mang_id

MATSH.Voistkond_1_id and Voistkond_2_id are same as in VOISTKONNAD.Voistkond_id

The all 3 tables have all primary and forgein keys.

**MATSH**
[image]

**VOISTKONNAD**

[image]

**MANG**

[image]

But now I am trying to select from table info as the numbers are replace, but then there is a problem. That my Teine_voistkond is taking info from Voistkond_1_id not from Voistkond_2_id...

[image]

```
select MATSH.Matsh_id, MANG.Mang_nimi, MATSH.Voistkond_1_id, VOISTKONNAD.Voistkond_nimi  as Esimene_voistkond, MATSH. Voistkond_2_id, VOISTKONNAD.Voistkond_nimi  as Teine_voistkond, MATSH.Matsh_kuupaev, MATSH.Tulemus, MATSH.Muu_info
from MATSH
join MANG on MATSH.Mang_id = MANG.Mang_id 
join VOISTKONNAD on MATSH.Voistkond_1_id = VOISTKONNAD.Voistkond_id;
```

But I if i use

```
...
 join VOISTKONNAD on MATSH.Voistkond_1_id = VOISTKONNAD.Voistkond_id
join VOISTKONNAD on MATSH.Voistkond_2_id = VOISTKONNAD.Voistkond_id;
```

This gives me

> ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'VOISTKONNAD'

I tried with aliases. It gives me.

> Empty set (0.00 sec)

And with right and left join. It gives me again

> Empty set (0.00 sec)

As you probably can understand now, my problem lies in the fact that the Teine_voistkond is not showing the names it should show.

and i simpy find the mistake anymore.

Comment: Try using `JOIN VOISTKONNAD AS v1 ON on MATSH.Voistkond_1_id = v1.Voistkond_id` and `JOIN VOISTKONNAD AS v2 ON on MATSH.Voistkond_2_id = v2.Voistkond_id` and update your `SELECT` accordingly, i.e. something like `SELECT v1.Voistkond_nimi, v2.Voistkond_nimi, ...`

Comment: Why is this a picture?

Comment: @mahok changing them to `v1` `v2` and updating the `SELECT` is not working, it gives the same as in the 2nd picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select MATSH.*, MANG.*, VOISTKONNAD1.* , VOISTKONNAD.*
  from MANG
  INNER JOIN MATSH on MATSH.Mang_id = MANG.Mang_id 
  INNER JOIN VOISTKONNAD on MATSH.Voistkond_1_id = VOISTKONNAD.Voistkond_id
  INNER JOIN VOISTKONNAD AS VOISTKONNAD1 ON MATSH.Voistkond_2_id = VOISTKONNAD1.Voistkond_id
```

Comment: Thank you! Modifying this to my needs helped me alot!